# Forked repository mirroring failing

Tags: git, gitlab

I fail to update my forked repository https://gitlab.com/sourav_roy_gngl392/api from its parent repo  https://gitlab.com/mirach/kounsel/backend/api.

It runs into the following issue , 
"2:Fetching remote upstream failed: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address"

Please note I've followed these guides already but in vain,

1) https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/

2 ) https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html.

I've found a clue of the above error though which is, I'm perhaps specifying a wrong mirror user, in the above tutorial 1, the step 3 says: Setup the mirror user: it's the user whose new commits to the upstream project will be attributed to in your fork.

@minhaz, please can you provide me a correct mirror user.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a credential helper that might cache the wrong credentials:

```
git config credential.helper
```

Check also the exact URL associated with upstream

```
git remote -v upstream
```

If https is still not working, try for testing to switch to SSH:

```
git remote set-url upstream git@gitlab.com:<user>/<repo>
```